# Sending message to Telegram from Google Sheet via Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a telegram message to myself, every morning, with a different quote that I have listed in a Google Sheet. I wrote some code that adds messages to the list, but I can't seem to generate a random row from the list to send daily.

```
var token = "TOKEN"; 
var telegramAPI = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token; 
var webAppAPI = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/GOOGLE_WEB_APP_ADDRESS";
var ssId = "SPREADSHEET_ID"; 

function getMe() {
  var url = telegramAPI + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramAPI + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppAPI;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function sendText(id,text) {
  var url = telegramAPI + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Test Data" + JSON.stringify(e,null,4));
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e);  
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var what = data.message.text.split("-")[0]
  var who = data.message.text.split("-")[1]
  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name;
  var response = "Hi " + name + ", this quote has been added to your database: " + text;
  sendText(id,response);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[1].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,response,what,who]);
```

All of this works fine. I added a query that pulls them over to my Quote sheet from my Telegram Feed sheet, that I'll put here to help someone:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Telegram Feed'!$G$1:$G$98,"",-1),"Error")
```

Now that I'm pulling in quotes, I want to generate a random one from the list and schedule it to send to myself on a daily basis. I've included what I've tried below, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The randomizer is partially working, but seems to be grabbing all of the content, which I need to refactor to say something along the lines of:

```
message = f"{quote} + ' - ' + {author}"
```

Randomizer:

```
function randomizer() {
  var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  var ss = ssa.getSheetByName('Quotes'); 
  var range = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(), 2);
  var data = range.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
  { 
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(data[i].length));
    var element = data[i][j]; 
    ss.getRange(i+1, 6).setValue(element); 
    Logger.log(element);
  }
}
```

Up until this point, it mostly works (even though I need to figure out how to fix the randomizer function as mentioned above. It's when I try to send a random message from the script to Telegram that I run into problems.

```
function sendQuote(what,who) {
  var data = randomizer();
  var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data.postData.contents);
  var url = telegramAPI + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + 'CHAT_ID_NUM' + "&text=" + what + " - " who;
}
```

I'm getting nothing back. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I followed the suggestions from Дмитро-Булах & carlesgg97, and I refactored a bunch of my randomize code to give me a quote and author. For some reason, I'm now getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "postData" from undefined.: from the line that reads `var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data.postData.contents);`

Does anyone know why this is happening?
I'll close the issue within 24hrs regardless. Thanks for the help everybody!

```
function sendQuote(quote,author) {
  var data = randomize();
  var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data.postData.contents);
  var encodedText = encodeURIComponent(quote + " - " + author);
  var url = telegramAPI + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + 'CHAT_ID' + "&text=" + encodedText;
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
} 

function randomize() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Quotes');

  var length = ss.getLastRow();
  var overshoot = 97 //monitor for changes as list size increases
  var true_length = length-overshoot;   
  var line = (Math.random() * ((true_length - 2) + 1)) + 2;

  var quote_cell = ss.getRange(line,2);
  var quote = quote_cell.getValue();
  var author_cell = ss.getRange(line,1);
  var author = author_cell.getValue();
  Logger.log(quote + " - " + author);
}
```

Comment: don't you miss `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);` in `sendQuote(what,who)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you may be having two different problems:

1. You are not encoding the text as URL-safe. To safely append data (in this case the `text` URL Query string parameter) to your URL, you should use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).
2. You don't seem to actually be sending the request. Did you miss the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call?

See below an example that fixes both issues:

```js
function sendQuote(what,who) {
  var data = randomizer();
  var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data.postData.contents);
  var encodedText = encodeURIComponent(what + " - " + who);
  var url = telegramAPI + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + 'CHAT_ID_NUM' + "&text=" + encodedText;
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```